# Axios and Fetch is not working for my react Native app for android

Tags: android, react-native, axios, android-emulator

I am always getting Network error alert for the below API axios get request.
Please suggest what is wrong with my url given.
I read so many posts and i think my url is not correct.
I have added my ip with port number in between of https:// and api.
Kindly help what needs to be updated in the code.
React Native-Axios-Android Emulator

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';


function WelcomePage({ navigation }) {

const dataFetch = async () => {

    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://192.168.1.4:5554/reactnative.dev/movies.json');
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    }
    catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    };
}


return (
    <View>
        <Text>Welcome!</Text>
        <View>
            <Button
                title="Fetch Name and DOB"
                onPress={dataFetch}></Button>
            <Text></Text>
            <Button
                title="Go to Profile Page"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Cart")}></Button>
        </View>
    </View>
);
  }
  export default WelcomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `https://192.168.1.4:5554/reactnative.dev/movies.json`, but localhost doesn't support https, change to `http://192.168.1.4:5554/reactnative.dev/movies.json` it should work.